# How to pass a value to this function type

Tags: javascript

```
if (!window.statistics) window.statistics = {};

statistics.Update = function (var sales) {
    ...
}
```

Here I get the error `Unexpected token var` on the `var sales` argument.  I expect something like this is because I cannot pass any arguments to this type of function.  If I have the same function type without arguments it works.

Why is this and how do I pass a value to this function?

Comment: remove `var` and go like this `function(sales)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `var`, and your function will have one named argument. When you call it (you're never calling it in your code), you'd pass in whatever value you want it to receive in that named argument.

```
if (!window.statistics) window.statistics = {};

statistics.Update = function (sales) {
// No 'var' here -------------^

    console.log(sales);

}; // <== Off-topic: Note the semicolon

statistics.Update("foo"); // Logs "foo" to the console
```

Comment: Is that semicolon strict? Because I don't think I have ever used it on a function like this - even though it makes sense :-)

Comment: @Espen: The horror that is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9) will add it for you if you leave it off. :-) It's an expression (in this case, an assignment expression, `x = y`), and so you end the expression with a semicolon as you do all other outermost expressions. It's pretty much only function declarations and blocks associated with control statements (`if`, `while`) that don't need a semicolon to terminate them.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to give your parameters a name, you do not specify a value.

```
statistics.Update = function (sales) {
    ...
}
```

You can pass your value by calling the method like this:

```
var s = '';

statistics.Update(s);
```